# Springboot Hikari Oracle RAC jdbc connection error

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm getting error when deployingg project

INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
WARN  o.s.b.a.j.DataSourceHealthIndicator - DataSource health check failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc-url:...

Connection String

jdbc:oracle:thin:
@(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=1)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my2.org)(PORT=123))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my1.org)(PORT=123))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DG)))

Comment: remove space before @

Comment: It was.  Posted incorrectly

Comment: You have two ADDRESS tags but no ADDRESS_LIST. This looks wrong.